# I tried copying invisible files to a directory but I can't find it

Tags: command-line, unix

I just did this:

`$ cp .cordova && ../../../`

In Terminal (Mavericks). Totally forgot to include an actual path to a directory.

I went back to the directory where I thought .cordova was going to be in but it's not there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cp` command without a second operand will just fail with an error.

The `&&` doesn't count as an operand as it means "execute the following command if the first one succeeds".  The first command is the `cp` and would error, so the part after `&&` would be discarded.

If if it had the `..\..\..\` isn't a valid command, it is just a path.

So the `.cordova` directory will be in its original place and nowhere else.